# ImageView background in row

Tags: java, android, listview, imageview

I want to set the background image of an image resource in list row, how ever the following code has no affect on the background, it doesn't affect the background at all.

```
@Override
        public void bindView(View view, Context context, Cursor cursor) {

            TextView mobileNo=(TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.text1);
            mobileNo.setText(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(NotesDbAdapter.KEY_TITLE)));

            TextView frequency=(TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.date);
            frequency.setText(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(NotesDbAdapter.KEY_COLOR)));
            String color = (cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(NotesDbAdapter.KEY_COLOR)));

            ImageView background=(ImageView)view.findViewById(R.id.album_image);
            if (color == "#57a2f6"){
                background.setImageResource(R.drawable.bluebg);
            }
            else if (color == "#00cdb1"){
                background.setImageResource(R.drawable.redbg);
            }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you are trying to compare `String color` with `==` which is `not valid in java` so
use `eaquals()` `for comparison of Strings`

so your code should be

```
if (color.equals("#57a2f6")){
     background.setImageResource(R.drawable.bluebg);
    }
else if (color.equals("#00cdb1")){
     background.setImageResource(R.drawable.redbg);
    }
```